# How do I get access to template parameters of a template pack parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I am trying to create a template class that will enable a compare function to return an integer [ 0 - equal, >0 a should come first, <0 b should come first ].

I am using Sort structs template parameters to keep track of the type that should be used, offset of the field in the string, as well as the order that this field should be kept... so compare can according return the correct value.

Assume for now that the `std::string` is used to represent a serialized value.

I am having trouble with extracting the information from the template. I have kept `sort` as a pack parameter, which would be of the type `Sort`. How do I access these parameters in the code? If there is a better way to refactor this. I looked at some of the other questions related to templates, but didn't see any that would solve this problem. I am using gcc 8.2 and c++17.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cassert>

template<typename T, uint32_t offset, char Order = 'A'>
struct Sort {};

template<uint32_t keyLength, template<typename T,uint32_t offset, char Order> class ... sort>
class Comparator {
public:
      int compare(std::string & a, std::string &b) {
         assert(a.length()==b.length());
         // How would I sum the sizeof each T. i.e. if T is int and another T is short, then sum should be 6+keyLength?
         assert(a.length()==(sizeof(T)+keyLength)); // Check that my length is equal to key length + all type lengths put together
         auto r = memcmp(a.data(),b.data(),keyLength);
         if(r!=0) return r;
         // How do I retrieve T,offset,Order of each pack parameter.
         return internal_compare<T,offset,Order>(a.data(),b.data())? internal_compare<T,offset,Order>(a.data(),b.data()) : ...;

      }

private:
      template<typename IT,uint32_t iOffset, char iOrder>
      int internal_compare(char * a,char *b) {
         if constexpr (iOrder=='A'||iOrder=='a') {
            return (*(static_cast<IT *>(a+iOffset)))-(*(static_cast<IT *>(b+iOffset)));
         } else {
            return (*(static_cast<IT *>(b+iOffset)))-(*(static_cast<IT *>(a+iOffset)));
         }
      }
};
```

Two things I have not been able to accomplish.

- One is getting the sum of sizeof(T) from the sort.
- Call the internal compare operator on each sort.

[Link to code on compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/H8-145)

Comment: Forwarding the pack to a `std::tuple` and using `get()` seems to be the most easy way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This becomes substantially easier if instead of using this form:

```
template<typename T, uint32_t offset, char Order = 'A'>
struct Sort {};

template<uint32_t keyLength, template<typename T,uint32_t offset, char Order> class ... sort>
class Comparator;
```

You use this one:

```
template <uint32_t keyLength, class...>
class Comparator;

template <uint32_t keyLength, typename... T, uint32_t... offset, char... Order>
class Comparator<keyLength, Sort<T, offset, Order>...> {
    // ...
};
```

First, the original didn't do what you wanted to do anyway. You wanted specific instantiations of `Sort` but you were actually accepting *class templates*... like `Comparator<32, Sort, Sort, Sort>`. Which presumably isn't meaningful.

But when we do it this way, we're not only accepting only instantiations of `Sort` but we have the parameters in the most useful form. So something like this:

```
// How would I sum the sizeof each T. i.e. if T is int and another T is short,
// then sum should be 6+keyLength?
```

Is a fold-expression:

```
(sizeof(T) + ... + keyLength)
```

And so forth.

Answer (score 2):

I'll take this problem on another front: how do you extract the template parameters if `T` has template parameters? Here's an example:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T v) {
    // T is std::vector<int>, how to extract `int`?
}

int main() {
    foo(std::vector{1, 2, 3, 4});
}
```

There's many answers to that: extraction using partial specialization, type aliases and others.

Here's how you can do it for `std::vector`:

```
template<typename>
struct extract_value_type_t {};

template<typename T>
struct extract_value_type_t<std::vector<T>> {
    using type = T;
};

template<typename T>
using extract_value_type_t = typename extract_value_type<T>::type;

template<typename T>
void foo(T v) {
    // with template specialization
    using value_type = extract_value_type_t<T>;

    // with the member alias std::vector exposes
    // needs much less boilerplate!
    using value_type = typename T::value_type;
}
```

What does doing it with `T` when it's a vector gives us? Well, if you can do something with a simple type `T`, you won't even need a template template parameter, making your interface more flexible:

```
template<typename>
struct sort_traits {};

template<typename T, uint32_t offset_, char order_>
struct sort_traits<Sort<T, offset_, order_>> {
    using type = T
    static constexpr auto offset = offset_;
    static constexpr auto order = order_;
};
```

Then in your `Comparator` class, simply do something like that:

```
template<uint32_t keyLength, typename... sorts>
struct Comparator {
    int compare(std::string const& a, std::string const& b) {
       return (internal_compare<sorts>(a.data(), b.data()) && ...);
    }

private:
    template<typename sort>
    int internal_compare(char const* a, char const* b) {
       using traits = sort_traits<sort>;
       using type = typename traits::type;
       constexpr auto offset = traits::offset;
       constexpr auto order = traits::order;

       // do stuff
    }
};
```

This also add the possibility one day to add another kind of sort that would have different template parameters or different things exposed.

Comment: @JeJo yes it is mentionned. I tell that extraction is possible, as well as member type aliases.